# Firebase SAML Login from multiple identity providers - select provider?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, saml, saml-2.0

I'm using a SAML login via firebase angularfire (basically from here: https://medium.com/@tfalvo/single-sign-on-sso-for-your-firebase-app-with-saml-f67c71e0b4d6):

```
 let provider = new firebase.auth.SAMLAuthProvider('saml.jumpcloud-demo');
 firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
```

But I want to provide more than one SAML provider because I've different users, coming from different providers. Is there an opportunity to give users the chance to select the right one? Or do I've to make a SAML-login-button per provider?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve been looking at this and your could route them to the correct provider based on their domain?